# How to inject a Maybe value into MaybeT

Tags: haskell, monad-transformers

Say I have some `foo :: Maybe Int` and I want to bind it for example with `bar :: Int -> MaybeT (Writer String) Int`, what would be the idiomatic way to do that?

I could define my own `liftMaybe` function, and then use that, like:

```
let liftMaybe = maybe (fail "Nothing") return in liftMaybe foo >>= bar
```

But is there a more idiomatic (or at least concise) way to do that?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```haskell
MaybeT . return :: (Monad m) => Maybe a -> MaybeT m a
```

I think it's a shame it doesn't have a standard name, however doing [a hoogle search](https://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=Maybe%20a%20-%3E%20MaybeT%20m%20a), we see that the `relude` packages uses [`hoistMaybe`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/relude-0.7.0.0/docs/Relude-Monad-Trans.html#v:hoistMaybe):

```haskell
hoistMaybe :: Applicative m => Maybe a -> MaybeT m a
```

---

A more general form is

```haskell
liftMaybe :: (MonadPlus m) => Maybe a -> m a
liftMaybe = maybe mzero return
```

which is preferable to the use of `fail`. I'd just put it in a convenient module somewhere.

Comment: Thx, this is already an improvement. But can we do even better?

Comment: Than `maybe mzero return`? I doubt it; that's very short already. I don't suggest inlining this everywhere you use it; putting it into a common module is a much better idea.

Comment: This can also be seen as a specific use of something like `fmapT :: (Monad m, Monad n, MonadTransformer t) => (forall a. m a -> n a) -> (forall a. t m a -> t n a)`, but only if we pretend that `Maybe` is actually `MaybeT Identity`. I don't think that function is possible in full generality, but could be made into a type class with specific monad transformers as instances.

Comment: I think you mean `t n b` there.

Comment: `t n a`, actually. Ugh, this is why I need a type checker.

Comment: I think it is interesting that the results from Hayoo for `Maybe a -> m a` are more relevant then [those from Hoogle](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=Maybe+a+-%3E+m+a) (at least it came as a surprise to me).

Comment: Hayoo searches all of Hackage; Hoogle only searches a much smaller set of packages (but it does more fancy unification tricks with the queries). For seeing what names people use to name standard combinators like this, Hayoo is the best bet. (BTW, in case you don't know: You can click the tick-mark next to an answer to accept it.)

Comment: The `errors` packages names it `hoistMaybe`: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/errors-1.4.7/docs/Control-Error-Util.html